# Blender crashes when render call back calls render

Tags: python, rendering

I am trying to hook up an additional blender script after the rendering is done, to render the same scene with different parameters and to do some additional processing there.

I have simplified my code, to make it easier to understand the problem but still keep it reproducible:

```
import bpy

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.clear()

render = True

def my_handler(scene):

    # prevent recursion
    global render
    
    if render:
        render = False
        # render something else with other parameters
        temp = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "H:/folder/img_2.png"
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = temp
        render = True

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(my_handler)
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

This code works fine, when I execute it, it will render automatically, since it is triggered in the last line **bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True**) and will render the original scene. Since it is hooked up with the handler **render_complete** it will then render a second image.
This works like a charm.
But if I try to trigger it using **F12** it crashes (almost every time) at this part **bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)** inside the **my_handler** function.

I can't manage to figure out why, since when it is triggered through the script there are now problems. It this small example nothing is shown in the Python-Console, Blender just crashes.
But in my original code, that does some more processing there is an error that is in the crash log too:

```
ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x00007FF7EBC994CF
Exception Module      : blender.exe
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
```

Do you have any pointers for me?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on my end. You could try testing it on a fresh install of Blender in a fresh project with no settings altered and see if the problem persists - if not, perhaps it's related to your configuration, otherwise it might be related to your operating system. There could also be some compatibility issue with some addon that e.g. also subscribes to the `render_complete` event.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, what devices are you using for rendering if it works? Doing stuff after render in a script has always been difficult because of multithreading and other stuff I don't understand. Is it no longer the case?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I just tried on 3.4.1 on Windows. Running the script would save one image based on my settings, and another image (well the same really in regards to contents) in the path given in the script. Pressing F12 would open the render result window but also save another image in the path given in the script (I deleted the image before the test), no crash happened.

Comment: OK, so the problem here could be: the handler seems to execute when rendering is complete correctly, but the code in the handler starts another render and there are commands after that. If I understand it correctly, there will be issues if you try to start rendering and run other Python code immediately after because the script will not wait for rendering process to be finished correctly as rendering happens in other threads and even on other devices. The script somehow works for me as well without crash, but that's the thing I find more surprising than it crashing.

Comment: Of course, the question itself might still be an XY problem. If you need to start another render after one, why not use View Layers to render whatever you need in multiple layers?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Since you told me it is not reproducable for you, I tried it again on a fresh project.
Turns out that it works with the fresh project so far. 
I hope I can figure out what the problem with my original scene is, since it is still weird that it should do the same thing in both cases but one of them crashes. I will try to keep you up to date

Comment: Update: even with the new scene, when I pres ctrl + F12 instead of F12 it crashes.
Does it crash for you? @MarkusvonBroady

Comment: @AMGEBEE it does crash for me. Perhaps once you start a rendering job, some render-specific resources are frozen and you're not allowed to use them before the rendering finishes.